# update query with inner join [0 rows updated]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, inner-join

While updating data in a table1 with `inner join` returning `O row updated`, both the table are in different database. I got alternate method to update this, but I don't why my `INNER JOIN` query gone wrong.

**Not working with inner join**

```
UPDATE DB1.table1 
SET t1.column3='value3' 
from DB1.table1 t1 
INNER JOIN DB2.table2 t2 on t1.column2=t2.column2 
WHERE (t1.column1 = 'value1')
AND (t2.column3 = 'value3')
```

**Working query without using inner join.**

```
UPDATE DB1.table1 SET column3='value3' WHERE (column1 = 'value1')
AND (column3 = 'value3') AND (column2 in (select column2 from DB2.table2
where column3='value3' and column3='value3' and column4='value4'))



DB1..table1
column1 column2 column3 column4
c1  c2  c3a c4
c1  c2  c3a c4
c1  c2  c3b c4
c1  c2  c3b c4

DB2..table2
column1 column2 column3 column4
c1  c2  c3a c4
c1  c2  c3a c4
c1  c2  c3b c4
```

Can any body suggest this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax error in your statement. Use alias in SET and UPDATE part or use TableName, don't mix:

```
UPDATE t1
SET column3='value3' 
from DB1.table1 t1 
INNER JOIN DB2.table2 t2 on t1.column2=t2.column2 
WHERE (t1.column1 = 'value1')
AND (t2.column3 = 'value3')
```

Answer (score 1):

in your first query which does not works you have:

```
UPDATE DB1.table1 
SET t1.column3='value3'
.
.
.
```

you mentioned the actual name of the table for `update` but in `set` statement you have used the `alias` so there is a confusion.

and in second one you told:

```
UPDATE DB1.table1 SET column3= ...
```

you have used the actual name of table and column and there is nothing wrong here and the code works fine.

**So** when you use aliases then try to use it in Update part also **OR** use the actual names everywhere, the below tow query should work for you:

```
UPDATE DB1.table1 
SET DB1.table1.column3=DB2.table2.column3  
FROM DB1.table1
JOIN DB2.table2 ON DB1.table1.column2=DB2.table2.column2 
                AND DB1.table1.column1 = 'value1'
                AND DB2.table2.column3 = 'value3'
```

and

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.column3=t2.column3  
FROM DB1.table1 t1
JOIN DB2.table2  t2 ON t1.column2=t2.column2 
                    AND t1.column1 = 'value1'
                    AND t2.column3 = 'value3'
```

Comment: I found my mistake, you right thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating `DB1.table1` but Setting the Column `t1.Column3` that is why you are getting no rows updated

You Should do something like this

```
UPDATE DB1.table1 
SET DB1.table1.column3='value3'
FROM DB1.table1 t1
INNER JOIN DB2.table2 t2 on t1.column2= t2.column2 
WHERE (t1 .column1 = 'value1')
AND (t2.column3 = 'value3')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax you need to use for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE t1 SET 
t1.column3 = 'value3' 
FROM DB1.table1 t1
INNER JOIN DB2.table2 t2 ON t1.column2 = t2.column2 
WHERE 
(t1.column1 = 'value1') AND 
(t2.column3 = 'value3')
```